# Customize the style/class of a Material2 MdMenu

Tags: angular-material2

The [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api) is a little sparse on how to modify a menu...either that or I'm just dense.  How could I, for example, just change the backcolor of a menu to red?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the `class` input on your `md-menu`:

`app.component.html`:

```html
<button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="moreMenu">Menu</button>
<md-menu #moreMenu="mdMenu" class="myMenu">
    <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</md-menu>
```

`styles.css` (For some reason it doesn't work in `styleUrls`):

```css
.myMenu {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/WDB9cSpjHJuA9qllgINM?p=preview)

By the way, the thing you were looking for is this:

[image: <code>@Input('class') classList</code>]

Comment: Thank you.  My mistake was putting the class in the components css instead of the styles.css.